# Is there a way to access S3 while relying only on software.amazon.awssdk:s3:2.17.173?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-eks, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I use S3AsyncClient to access my bucket. S3AsyncClient is created as follows:

```
S3AsyncClient s3Client = S3AsyncClient.builder().region(Region.of(region)).build();
```

Then I read S3Object using async as follows:

```
GetObjectRequest objectRequest = GetObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucket).key(key).range(range).build();
        asyncClient.getObject(objectRequest, AsyncResponseTransformer.toBytes()).whenComplete((res, error) -> {
            doResponse(res, error);
        });
```

My code is deployed in EKS. The POD it's in has access to the same bucket location on S3 via aws cli. The response of using aws sts get-caller-identity on this POD and using stsClient in the code is only different in the userId part, and the account and role are the same.

The weird thing is when I remove the dependency software.amazon.awssdk:sts from the program, it won't be able to access S3 in POD. The response code is 403 and the message is Access Denied.

I didn't see in the Developer guide - AWS SDK for Java 2.x that accessing S3 must depend on sts. So, does anyone know what is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**STS is (Security Token Service)**, and that is what it is using in order to allow you access to S3 from the POD.

Once you removed the `awssdk:sts` dependency, you essentially removed all logic communicating with this service to authenticate S3AsyncClient.

According to this, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html  it is best to provide a Role (Which has access to S3) to your EKS Service Account.

Otherwise, credentials can be provided to the S3 Client directly, but this is not the recommended way to do it:

```
 AwsCredentialsProvider creds = StaticCredentialsProvider.create(AwsBasicCredentials.create("accessKey","secretKey"));


S3AsyncClient.builder().credentialsProvider(creds)
                    .region(Region.US_WEST_1)
                    .build();
```